# What is the best vs2008 theme you have seen

Tags: visual-studio

What is the best vs2008 theme you have seen.

I have been looking for a   theme that looks like the borland turbo  c of so long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has a blog post regarding Visual Studio Themes Gallery http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I really like [this theme by Oren Ellenbogen](http://www.lnbogen.com/VisualStudioNet2005Colors.aspx).

http://www.lnbogen.com/content/binary/ide_colors_regular.png

It reminds me of the elegant 'Dust' theme in Ubuntu. You can get it [here](http://www.lnbogen.com/ct.ashx?id=fc104328-6299-4eb1-a203-84b686aa4c5b&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.lnbogen.com%2fcontent%2fbinary%2fOrenEllenbogen_DarkSchema.rar).

Answer (score 1):

I like Damien's Humane theme, combined with EnvyCodeR VS font.  or Vibrant Ink.

Answer (score 1):

I use [zen-burn settings](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000682.html). The actual download link was from MSDN a while ago and I think this may be the actual version a guy based his off of. I can't remember the name of him to be completely honest.

[image: Zen-Burn]
<sub>(source: [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/visual-studio-2005-font-and-color-scheme-zenburn.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I find this theme real good for VS2008

Answer (score 0):

I like one from [CodingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000682.html). It is not the best but I like it at this time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use Ragnarok Grey. It was featured by hanselman, but on the authors site there are some more:
http://winterdom.com/category/vs-color-scheme